# Jasmine spy on new object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

I have a TypeScript (eventually testing the actual JavaScript) method I'm trying to test. It's pretty simple:

```
private static myMethod(foo: IFoo): void {
    let anInterestingThing = new InterestingThing();
    foo.bar = anInterestingThing.getSomethingCool();
}
```

I want to test that `getSomethingCool` has been called and normally, I would just do a simple `spyOn` but I can't figure out how to spy on the new `anInterestingThing` object. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is not possible. You can not know what the reference will be when you new the object. As far as I know, this is simply non-testable code. Either refactor it with dependency injection with a factory function.

Answer (score 0):

*If* `getSomethingCool` is a prototype method, you could write

```
jasmine.spyOn(InterestingThing.prototype, "getSomethingCool");
```

However, this is going to be quite fragile in practice. `InterestingThing` might change to make `getSomethingCool` an instance member, or capture a reference to the prototype function during its static constructor, etc.